# How to access the Published Date for creating a plug-in in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, plugins, joomla2.5

I've not found a Joomla extension that does this. In some Joomla Articles I needed to be able to have the `Published on` date display in a different section of the Article. I'm considering writing a plug-in to do this so I can do something like this as needed in the body of Article:

```
{published-on}
```

Where can I access the `Published on` contents for display? Also, for Joomla development experts is this the best way to solve this or is there another approach? Thanks!

Comment: You can achieve this using : 
--> Put {published-on}{/published-on} tags in your articles.

--> Create a content plugin which replaces these tags with the published on date.

You can edit this Joomla Plugin according to your requirements.

https://github.com/jitendra-khatri/jcontenthider

Hope this plugin will helps you.

Comment: Do you need to do this for a category of articles? If ever article in a particular category needs to display the publish date in a different section of the article, just use a template override. Much faster and easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for this, Also you're approach is in right way only one thing you have to consider your custom plugin never use something Joomla may use short codes like `{loadposition} , {loadmodule}` etc .

so make your short code in that way. and plugin can create `onContentPrepare()` event with Joomla.

you will get all the details of current article in `$article` parameters. like

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0){
             $article->text;
             $article->created_on;

}
```

For more clearness you have to check Joomla's default plugin used for placing module inside article. you can find the path `plugins\content\loadmodule`

Hope it make sense..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a template override if feasible.  This way you can enable/disable using the core back-end article administration UI while still having implicit control of the published dates display location.

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla